# How to output multiple pages in gnuplot cairolatex terminal?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

As written in the title, I am trying to create a multipage pdf with gnuplots cairolatex terminal.
I am using `gnuplot 5.4` in cygwin.

Single page works fine, i.e.

```
./gnuplot-script
pdflatex plot.tex
```

However when I plot multiple pages in the gnuplot-script, the output .tex file seems to contain errors ..
E.g. the gnuplot-script

```
set terminal cairolatex standalone
set output "plot.tex"
plot x
plot x**2
```

outputs a `plot.tex` that contains ***two*** `\documentclass{minimal}` and `pdflatex` then complains with

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
...
l.181 \documentclass
                    {minimal}
```

I can workaround this by putting each plot into a new file, but it seems a bit strange that simple multipage output is bugged in this terminal?

Am I missing some special command to start a new page in the cairolatex terminal or something? I don't see anything in the [documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf) for this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to create a TeX-based multipage pdf file directly from gnuplot, I suggest to use the `tikz` terminal rather than `cairolatex`.

```
set terminal tikz standalone
set output "plot.tex"
plot x
plot x**2
unset output
!pdflatex plot
```